# linking js and imacro to auto fill a form

Tags: javascript, forms, loops, webforms, imacros

Ok well im running imacro on a website.. And im running it so that it will fill out all the fields for me number times without me having to keep doing it over and over again.

This its website where the form is that im trying to auto fill: http://ohiohiphopawards.com/vote-now/2013-nominations

For the email at the bottom i want to enter a different email every time the macro loops.

So for that i have a javascript code.. Well the code is big and so i made another one that is smaller:

```
myfruits = new Array();myfruits.push("Strawberry");
myfruits.push("Banana");
myfruits.push("Kiwi");
myfruits.push("Orange");
myfruits.push("Mango");


function getFruit() {
for(i=0;i<10;i++) //change 10 to the number of times you want it to be ran
{
   randomint = Math.floor(Math.random()*myfruits.length);
   }
   return  myfruits[randomint];
}
   iimSet("fruit",myfruits[randomint]); //in the macro you can access the random fruit through {{fruit}} much like you would {{!VAR1}}
   iimPlay("fruitmacro.iim");
```

And the imacro code is this:

```
VERSION BUILD=8300326 RECORDER=FXTAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://ohiohiphopawards.com/vote-now/2013-nominations
WAIT SECONDS=0
FRAME NAME="iframe"
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:take ATTR=NAME:answer[8] CONTENT=KPT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:take ATTR=NAME:answer[18] CONTENT=KPT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:take ATTR=NAME:answer[20] CONTENT=BloodSho
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:take ATTR=NAME:answer[25] CONTENT=KPT<SP>-<SP>Welcome<SP>Back
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:take ATTR=NAME:answer[35] CONTENT=KPT<SP>ft<SP>Snoop<SP>Doff<SP>&<SP>Bella<SP>Nae<SP>-<SP>How<SP>It<SP>Goes
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:take ATTR=NAME:answer[41] CONTENT=KPT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:take ATTR=ID:email CONTENT={{fruit}}
WAIT SECONDS=5
```

Unfortunately when you get to the bottom email part.. instead of going to the various options that were given in the js file i keep getting **"_*undefined*_"**

Anyone know how to fix this? So that instead of undefined i will get a different fruit name every time the macro loops?

P.S. The fruits are just random.. Ill change that to actual emails once the code works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getFruit() {
for(i=0;i<10;i++) //change 10 to the number of times you want it to be ran
{
   randomint = Math.floor(Math.random()*myfruits.length);
   }
   return  myfruits[randomint];
}
   iimSet("fruit",myfruits[randomint]); //<-- This is your problem
   iimPlay("fruitmacro.iim");
```

You set the "fruit" outside the loop. I don't think it can be accessed this way.
Try it like this

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++) //change 10 to the number of times you want it to be ran
{
   randomint = Math.floor(Math.random()*myfruits.length);
   iimSet("fruit",myfruits[randomint]);
   iimPlay("fruitmacro.iim");
   }
```

For your macro to loop, you need to place the iimSet and iimPlay **inside** that loop, else it will not be able to access your variables.

You can design any number of loops and switch statements, but the thing is you need to make sure which macro is played at what time and how the variables are set.
I hope it helps

******edited here*************
This is the content of my js file:

```
var fruitmacro;
    fruitmacro =  "CODE:";
    fruitmacro +=  "VERSION BUILD=7601105 RECORDER=FX" + "\n";
    fruitmacro +=  "URL GOTO=http://ro-bot.fr/flish/01.html" + "\n";
    fruitmacro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:take ATTR=ID:email CONTENT={{fruit}}" + "\n";
    fruitmacro +=  "WAIT SECONDS=5" + "\n";

var myfruits = ["apple","orange","peach","grapes"];
for(i=0;i<10;i++) 
{
   randomint = Math.floor(Math.random()*myfruits.length);
   iimSet("fruit",myfruits[randomint]);
   iimPlay(fruitmacro);
   }
```

And this is the content of the html file:

```
<input type="text" name="take" id="email" size="100" maxlength="100" /><br />
```

It is tested and it works. There must be something else in your code that breaks.

***edit2*********

mind the ; " and such - there might be issues

Comment: I tried to do it like that.. Unfortunately im stilling getting _Undefined_

Answer (score 0):

```
function exec (command){
    var headerCommand = "CODE:\nVERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX\n";
    iimPlay(headerCommand + command);
};

exec("URL GOTO=http://xxx");
exec("TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:txt_Username CONTENT=root");
alert ($('iframe[id=frameContent]').contents().find('#wlSsid').val());
```